# What can be said about this stochastic integral?

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process defined on $\mathbb R$ such that all sample paths are right-continuous, non-decreasing, bounded between 0 and 1, $X_{-\infty}=0$, $X_\infty = 1$.

What can be said about the integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty s \, {X_s}^m \, dX_s$$

where $m=0,1,...,n$.

Can we prove that those integrals make sense (so that indeed $X_t$ is a semimartingale and that $s \, {X_s}^m$ is in $L^1(X)$) and are finite $a.s$ ? Can we get a nice expression for them ? Any pieces of information, even for some $m$'s,  are welcome.

What are the tools to study such integrals besides change of variable formula and generalized Itô's lemma ? I only know those results for processes on $\mathbb R^+$, is it safe to assume they work in a similar way on $\mathbb R^-$ ?

Comment: Since $X$ is non-decreasing, then it has finite variation (and thus a semimartingale, but...). You can then interpret your integral as a (pathwise) Stieltjes integral.